# microsoft oauth2 v2.0 redirect_uri is not valid

Tags: adal, onedrive

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/) so that I can authenticate to my OneDrive account, but I get the following error:

> The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not
>   valid. The expected value is
>   'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a  URL which matches
>   the redirect URI registered for this client application.

Steps I took:

1. Registered a New app
2. gave it a name
3. chose the web platform
4. specified https://localhost as the redirect URI
5. pressed save
6. created this url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=d0adff4f-bcae-4a69-80a7-8a3328a6cf89&scope=openid+profile&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https://localhost&nonce=49458204719374587149482
7. pasted url into browser and pressed enter
8. a login page appears with my app name and I select my account to login with. I'm then redirect and shown the "redirect_uri" is not valid message

Any idea why I'm not getting a token response back?

Comment: When you created app in Azure AD what did you specify as redirect_uri? Was it `https://localhost`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried several different variations for the redirect_uri. https://localhost, http://localhost, and even deployed to a live azure url

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support issue not involving programming.

Answer (score -2):

Try https://localhost/somepath instead of https://localhost 
Or you can even use http instead https, but provide some path or html page after localhost.